# When I provide 100% width to my html and body tag along with a border in css, why is my body border crossing the html border?

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html and CSS and was exploring the `html` and `body` tag and when I applied 100% `height` to both html and body tag along with a border, the border for body was crossing over the html border. I want to know why is this happening. Can anyone help me with an explanation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set both the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on both of those elements to `border-box` and the margin on the body to zero:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin:0;
}

html {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

The body has a default margin in pretty much every browser, and the box-sizing change is needed to account for the way the box [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) is calculated.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was helpful.